# Stuck with a Hypergeometric Distribution Probability Problem - Need Help

Tags: probability, statistics

I need help with this problem. It feels like I am doing something wrong but I am unsure what is it. I have no answers to refer to and I'm preparing for an exam so any help is much appreciated! Thank you for your time in advance!

In a package with 12 cookies, there are 3 cookies which are accidentally salty. If a person randomly takes four cookies without replacement, what will be the probability that at most one of the cookies will be salty.

So, essentially, it seems that we have Hypergeometric distribution with N=12 K=3 n=4 and k=1

So we need to calculate $P(k=1)$ and $P(k=0)$ or so I thought.

By using: $P(k)=[\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}]:\binom{N}{n}$ and plug in the above values we get:

$P(0)=[\binom{3}{0}\binom{12-3}{9-0}]:\binom{12}{4}=0.50$

$P(1)=[\binom{3}{1}\binom{12-3}{9-1}]:\binom{12}{4}=0.5$ yet again and that's where I'm confused.

Where did I go wrong? Any help will be much much appreciated as I'm preparing for an exam! Thank you in advance!

Comment: $n-k = 4-k$ when $n=4$

Answer (score 1):

Use :
$${\binom 30 = 1\\\binom31=3\\\binom {12-3}{\mathbf 4-0}=126\\ \binom{12-3}{\mathbf 4-1}=84\\\binom{12}{4}=495}$$